# How to merge multiple function in single query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to combine 3-4 functions inside one function and call this inside another function. for example

```
public function todayordercount(){       
  $sql  =  "SELECT *,count(id) FROM `tbl_order` WHERE DATE(`date_added`) = CURDATE() and status='Delivered'";
  $query   = $this->db->query($sql);
  if($query->num_rows()>0){
    return  $query->result_array();
  }else{
    return $query->row_array(); 
  }       
}

public function currentmonthcount(){       
  $sql  =  "SELECT sum(amount) as amt,sum(shipping) as shiping,sum(commission) as commission,sum(base_price) as base_price,sum(tax_amt) as tax,SUM(LENGTH(product_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(product_id, ',', '')) + 1) as unit , count(id) FROM `tbl_order` WHERE MONTH(CURDATE())=MONTH(date_added) and status='Delivered'";
  $query   = $this->db->query($sql);

  if($query->num_rows()>0){
    return  $query->result_array();
  }else{
    return $query->row_array(); 
  }       
}
```

Comment: Elaborate your question for better clearance...

Comment: `SELECT *, COUNT(id)` without GROUP BY is wierd SQL.. and is not future proof when MySQL servers are running sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'... Also `SUM(LENGTH(product_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(product_id, ',', '')) + 1) as unit`   looks like bad database design by using CSV in a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function mergeordercount(){

 $query1 =  $this->db->query("SELECT *,count(id) as today_order FROM `tbl_order` WHERE DATE(`date_added`) = CURDATE() and status='Delivered'");

 $query2 =  $this->db->query("SELECT sum(amount) as amt,sum(shipping) as shiping,sum(commission) as commission,sum(base_price) as base_price,sum(tax_amt) as tax,SUM(LENGTH(product_id) - LENGTH(REPLACE(product_id, ',', '')) + 1) as unit , count(id) FROM `tbl_order` WHERE MONTH(CURDATE())=MONTH(date_added) and status='Delivered'");

$query3 =  $this->db->query("SELECT count(status) as status FROM `tbl_order` WHERE MONTH(CURDATE())=MONTH(date_added) and status='Return'");    

$query4 =  $this->db->query("SELECT count(response) as calls FROM `tbl_order` WHERE response='pending' or response='hold'");        

$query5 =  $this->db->query("SELECT count(id) as product FROM `tbl_product`");    

 $result1   =  $query1->row_array();    
 $result2   =  $query2->row_array();    
 $result3   =  $query3->row_array();    
 $result4   =  $query4->row_array();         
 $result5   =  $query5->row_array();     
 return array_merge($result1, $result2, $result3, $result4, $result5); 
 }
```

you should do look like above code it will help you bettor.
Thank You...